# Postgres: psql: FATAL: database "root" does not exist in windows 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Please check below command which I had run:

```
C:\Windows\system32>psql -U root
Password for user root:
psql: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify which database you want to connect to, `psql` will use the database with the same name as the database user.

Since you specified database user `root`, `psql` tries to connect to a database of that name, but the database doesn't exist.

Try specifying an existing database:

```
psql -U root -d mydb
```

In case you don't know which database to use, or if you never created a database, you can always use the `postgres` database.

Comment: What if I don't have any database created?

Comment: That's the fastest response I've got on StackOverflow :D. Thanks for the info. Maybe you should add that to the answer so that it helps others :) .

Comment: This is probably the least useful behaviour from a well used tool that I've ever seen.